# Issue displaying XLSXWriter file special characters in Google SPreadsheets (UTF8_decode)

Tags: google-sheets, export-to-csv, xlsx

I am using XLSXWriter php library to generate xlsx files that have special characters in a few columns .

The encoding is UTF8 and the special chars seem to display correctly both on my website and when I open them with excel .

The strange thing is that when I import the file to Google Spreadsheets there is just a bunch of squares and characters that do not match the original .

Example : âðð¼ð¼â
ð³ð¾ð±: ð¸ð¾ ð³ð´ð² ð¸ð¶

What I have tried to fix the issue :

1. I use utf8_decode to convert my strings before exporting the file
2. I tried a composer library (forceutf8) in order to fix any errors related to utf8 double encoding
3. I tried to export directly using UTF-8 encoding but the columns are empty when I do this

I don't really know what else to try, supposely google spreadsheets should read UTF8 encoding and even if it didn't, it makes no sense that when I use utf8_decode the characters are displaying correctly in Excel but not in Google Spreadsheets .

Any suggestion, been trying to fix this for several hours .

Thanks

Comment: did you try to play with fonts in GS?

Comment: can you share a sample excel file? I tried to use your example and create a csv file and it was successfully imported in Google Sheets